# Filling gaps and holes in dry wall

Tags: drywall, hole-repair

We had an electrician come to do some work, and he had to move an outlet from one area to another, and do some other stuff on another portion of the wall.  I'm left with a square outlet-shaped cut out in my dry wall, as well as another cut out that he filled and nailed together. How can I fix these?

[image]
[image]

Comment: did he completely remove the wiring?

Comment: @depperm: yes he did

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first repair is a piece of cake. Get some drywall tape and a bucket of joint compound and tape away. Rather than explain it here, just Google "taping drywall" and you'll get more information than I could ever provide.

The second one is little trickier because you'll have to support a square plug of drywall. You can get drywall clips from your home store just for this purpose. You can also get a strip on wood a few inches longer the hole and screw it into the inside portion of the hole from the outside. Then cut your plug and place it in the hole and secure it to your support with a few drywall screws, the tape like you did to the first one.

If you think you'll ever have to access the second hole for other electrical work, you can just mount a blank outlet cover over the hole.

Comment: Another way to fill the second one, without needing clips or a block of wood, is a California patch. Search for videos for the details, but the basics are: get a scrap of drywall about three inches larger than the hole, in both directions; cut from the back, most of the way through, in the shape of the hole; snap off the material, but leave the paper on the face; mud it in, using the paper flaps to hold it in place.

Comment: @DougDeden: Just saw a few videos re California patching, looks very easy! I think I may end up doing that. Thanks for sharing!